# Store value in database using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to store values in database using a stored procedure. I have a column `IS_USER_ACTIVE`.

My condition is,

- `IS_USER_ACTIVE="active"`: I want store that value "Y" in DB.
- `IS_USER_ACTIVE="inactive"`: I want store that value "N" in DB.

How can I write this condition in a stored procedure?

```js
USE [VIQ]
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test] 
    @a int,
    @b varchar(20),
    @dat varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
 --select * from VIQ_MA_USERS3 where first_name=@b --
 INSERT INTO VIQ_MA_USERS3(company_id,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL_ID,PASSWORD,user_creation_date,USER_STATUS_LAST_UPDATED_DATE,LAST_LOGIN_DATE) 
    VALUES(@a, @b, @b, @b, @b,
           CONVERT(Datetime, @dat, 101),
           CONVERT(Datetime, @dat, 101),
           CONVERT(Datetime, @dat, 101));
END
```

Comment: I haven't see any column IS_USER_ACTIVE in your table, further what's the point of selecting data from VIQ_MA_USERS3 and inserting again in VIQ_MA_USERS3 table? Your condition for active user checking is also missing in stored procedure.

Comment: Try to use **more meaningful** names than `@a` and `@b` for your parameters. Also: if `@dat` is a date, it should be of type `DATE` or `DATETIME` - and not varchar ....

Answer (score 3):

Use case statement:

```
Case IS_USER_ACTIVE when 'active'   Then 'Y'  
                    when 'Inactive' Then 'N' else <some value> end
```